# Write an NFA with only four states

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$, consider the language $L = \{111\}$, i.e., $L$ contains a single string with three $1$’s.  Give an NFA with $4$ states that recognizes $L$...

I am kind of stuck since I can only think of having one with $5$ states, with the last state being a garbage or catch all state that makes sure four or more quantity of $1$'s are not accepted. any intuition would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with $q_0 \xrightarrow[]{1} q_1 \xrightarrow[]{1} q_2 \xrightarrow[]{1} q_f$?

Comment: @Babado what if a user adds another one after that, where do I make that last 1 arrow point to? That is the problem I am running into

Comment: You just don't draw an arrow. By convention, any letter which is not in the arrows goes to the rejecting state (for example, I didn't write any zeroes, this means that if a zero comes,  it goes to the rejecting state)

Comment: @Babado oh ok thanks, I thought for some reason I had to include very possible input combination for my NFA. Just as a followup, I wouldn't be able to write a DFA with 4 states that can recognize L right? Just an NFA would be possible

Comment: The DFA would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand Babado's comment, the automaton
$$
\rightarrow (1) \xrightarrow{1} (2) \xrightarrow{1} (3) \xrightarrow{1} (4) \rightarrow
$$
is indeed an automaton accepting the language $\{111\}$. This automaton is an *incomplete* deterministic automaton and hence also a non-deterministic automaton.
It is actually the minimal incomplete deterministic automaton accepting $\{111\}$.
The minimal *complete* deterministic automaton of $\{111\}$ would be the $5$-state automaton ${\cal A} = (Q, \{0,1\}, \cdot, i, F)$ with $Q = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $i = 1$, $F = \{4\}$ and the transitions given by the following table
\begin{array}{c|c|}
q & 1 & 2 & 3 &4 & 0\\
\hline
q \cdot 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
\hline
q \cdot 1 &1 &1 &1 &1&0\\
\hline
\end{array}
Note that $0$ is a *sink state* of $\cal A$.